# How do I create a Progress Bar in vega-lite?

Tags: vega-lite

Could someone please show me how to create a simple Progress Bar in vega-lite using the following data? Thanks in advance.

| SEGMENT | ACHIEVED | REMAINING |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Enterprise | 73.1% | 26.9% |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can do something like this ([view in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUWGA5gLYYB2U8IAopRgE4AODAloSADQgQDGAFqwyIMYeAAYAdAHYAzAEZuDDCQity6ohMkAmAGwBOAL4BdI9ygMI5LADMA9gxJ5QDlGLi4eAoSLFKVNQ1yLRNuCBxPEBQIACMMFC4QJkZeChgiDBAzMJBVBgBraliIBiSKXnswTXhQAE9akFshd2pCUnSkqDqU6nJ7EnVUEHMQAA9G5oSPZNT0iEyunqy4EABHNGsoVhhtkSSIMfZJx1UqVclxAFIR0cqUR0mWmZj4xItlvoGhxKM-oA)):

```json
{
  "data": {
    "values": [{"segment": "Enterprise", "achieved": 0.731, "remaining": 0.269}]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"fold": ["achieved", "remaining"], "as": ["label", "percentage"]}
  ],
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"field": "segment", "type": "nominal"},
    "x": {
      "field": "percentage",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {"format": ".0%"}
    },
    "color": {"field": "label", "type": "nominal"}
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks! Am I right in assuming that the key to making this work is the Fold transform?