# What type of Vega marks to show a point along a scale? (see image)

Tags: vega

I am attempting to create a visualization where we are showing a score along a scale, something like this:
[image: chart showing a point along a scale, with low, mid, and high breaks shown]

The scale is based on quartiles of a large dataset (these are pre-calculated and don’t need to be calculated within Vega). In this particular example, the scale looks like this:

| Break | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Min | 0 |
| Low | 26.3 |
| Mid | 42.9 |
| High | 54.8 |
| Max | 70.7 |

So in the example image above, the score we are reporting is something like 56 (I will display the score with a tooltip).

At this point, I’m not even sure what type of marks I should be using in Vega to attempt to create this display. Any help getting started is greatly appreciated!

Comment: perhaps might be of interested https://docs.relational.ai/rel/how-to/data-visualization-vegalite

Comment: @jspcal That seems like a good reference for folks starting with Vega-Lite, but I need to use Vega for this project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a Progress Bar in vega-lite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71293971/how-do-i-create-a-progress-bar-in-vega-lite)

Comment: Don't forget that Vega-Lite compiles to Vega...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a complete example in Vega.

[Open in Vega on-line editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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-WdYFDSNP27QxGkKdDNDNdp0mBTqDn2AwCBOAA5MBK24-CKoALwkyquPcrjKoAPwqmoKqqvoaquQFrXBSliZpRlwHRTlN1Be11XGnD9UqK551AqAC08wNuxHRq3TQV68rmZdNnhtGmN+A9Q3Pa9tkMDgPjbWzlQY1NcAABT4yF-K41IKq4mQqJ6sSACUKoALQqgIQ1xQLFvJV2NtVfbjvO670D6p7ADUvtDblwcc4VIvkpKKgCGVAuVSFNXp-VkJZ1zzWwwXrJwA0jXI6Nylo6AEMwnCorWVtZd1SAL49hLbDdZgNASujLu7k6Opu54x0nSrZkMG1iZXTdEbazGuuufr21GybN1m5HI-J6HdsO07Y-R8ShqKO7-vlQkQdBQfHFH7vuqn3AccqlbVtP+PKoAHzH8Pz8lQGgOJ7OmXt9ACEZiqCBl9+YTTapbYWpJRYwmaGtDabdbIQxAEwdO6DW5wAAOqKGUFg0WjRXJgTruNBuot9CTyVqdSoHoECMSyPPDWt1l5OT6I9Ny4gPIb2NvYU2gcAHtXvgucO-8o5ALfh-L+L9f4yPxC-c+ChQHewgVAmBicc6TWTkgnaBdUGuTHAgm+4jR4AO-n-RRQD1G0xVKsBmqovYuKGriAAXuDOhGg1owCQJuMh5dmw0HMRPGQVCdLtwpPQkuLVjEd1waaSeiIgA)

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "width": 400,
  "height": 100,
  "padding": 5,
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "data_segments",
      "values": [
        {"segmentLabel": "min", "segmentStart": 0, "segmentEnd": 26.3},
        {"segmentLabel": "low", "segmentStart": 26.3, "segmentEnd": 42.9},
        {"segmentLabel": "mid", "segmentStart": 42.9, "segmentEnd": 54.8},
        {"segmentLabel": "high", "segmentStart": 54.8, "segmentEnd": 70.7}
      ]
    }
  ],

  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "signal_score",
      "value": "56",
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 0, "max": 70.7, "step": 0.01, "name": "Score: "}
    },
  {
      "name": "signal_score_mid",
      "value": "42.9"
    }
    
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "scale_x",
      "type": "linear",
      "domain": {"data": "data_segments", "fields": ["segmentStart", "segmentEnd"]},
      "range": "width",
      "padding": 0.05,
      "round": true
    },
    {
      "name": "scale_y",
      "domain": [0, 1],
      "range": "height"
    },
    {
      "name": "scale_segment_color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": ["min", "low", "mid", "high"],
      "range": ["grey", "green", "orange", "red"]
    },
    {
      "name": "scale_segment_opacity",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": ["min", "low", "mid", "high"],
      "range": [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    { "orient": "bottom", "scale": "scale_x" },
    { "orient": "left", "scale": "scale_y",  "domainOpacity": 0, "tickOpacity": 0, "labelOpacity": 0}
  ],

  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data":"data_segments"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "scale_x", "field": "segmentStart"},
          "x2": {"scale": "scale_x", "field": "segmentEnd"},
          "y": {"scale": "scale_y", "value": 0.5},
          "y2": {"scale": "scale_y", "value": 0.7},
          "fill": {"scale": "scale_segment_color", "field": "segmentLabel"},
          "fillOpacity":{"scale": "scale_segment_opacity", "field": "segmentLabel"},
          "stroke": {"value": "white"}    
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "from": {"data":"data_segments"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "baseline": {"value": "top"},
          "fill": {"value": "black"},
          "fillOpacity": {"signal": "datum['segmentLabel'] == 'min' ? 0 : 1 "},
          "x": {"scale": "scale_x", "field": "segmentStart"},
          "y": {"scale": "scale_y", "value": 0.4},
          "text": {"field": "segmentLabel"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data":"data_segments"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "x": {"signal": "scale('scale_x', signal_score) - 5"},
          "x2": {"signal": "scale('scale_x', signal_score) + 5"},
          "y": {"scale": "scale_y", "value": 0.45},
          "y2": {"scale": "scale_y", "value": 0.75},
          "fill": {"value": "red"},
          "fillOpacity":{"value": 0.7},
          "stroke": {"value": "grey"},
          "tooltip": {"signal": "signal_score"} 
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "rule",
      "from": {"data":"data_segments"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "x": {"signal": "scale('scale_x', signal_score_mid)"},
          "x2": {"signal": "scale('scale_x', signal_score) + ((signal_score > signal_score_mid) ? -15 : 15)"},
          "y": {"scale": "scale_y", "value": 0.6},
          "stroke": {"value": "blue"},
          "strokeWidth": {"value": 2},
          "opacity": {"value": 1}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "symbol",
      "from": {"data":"data_segments"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "x": {"signal": "scale('scale_x', signal_score) + ((signal_score > signal_score_mid) ? -15 : 15)"},
          "y": {"scale": "scale_y", "value": 0.6},
          "angle": {"signal": "signal_score > signal_score_mid ? 90 : -90"},
          "size": {"value": 100},
          "shape": {"value": "triangle"},
          "opacity": {"value": 1},
          "fill": {"value": "blue"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Nice solution Roy.

Comment: This is really great, Roy! Thank you! I’m going to play around with it a bit to try to make one adjustment:
I want to have the breaks for low, mid, and high appear at the 25%, 50%, and 75% points on the visualization, even though the values underneath are not equal intervals. So I need to stretch the scale within each of the sections, essentially. I’ll follow up with whether I’m successful or not. Thanks again!